# C++ std::out_of_range aborted(core dumped)

Tags: c++, arrays, arraylist, vector

I have the following code (there's more to this code like push_back() and insert() but I cut those out for relevancy:

```
// In header file for class:
template <typename T>
class MyVector
{
  private: 
    T *m_data = nullptr; // Dynamic array or vector
    int reserved_size;   // Current max size of reserved_size
    int data_size;       // Current size of array
  public: 
    T & at(int index);
}

// In .hpp file for class
template <typename T> 
T & MyVector<T>::at(int index)
{
  if(index >= data_size)
    throw std::out_of_range ("Index out of range!");
  return m_data[index]
}

// In main
int main()
{
  MyVector<int> x;
  x.push_back(1);
  x.push_back(2);
  // Max size of the array here would be 5 and you're trying to access index 10
  x.at(10);
  // Should throw an error here
}
```

The problem is when I run the code it outputs: 
'terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
Aborted (core dumped)'

The array is filled with 5 values: 1,2,3,4,5 and the max size is set to 10.  I call at(20) which is obviously not in the index of my array m_data.  I don't know what the problem is that's causing a core dump here. 
EDIT: I know at this point I lack a catch for the throw, how would I go about adding this? I know how to do try-catch blocks for certain things but not for catching a std::out_of_range exception.

The directions for this assignment says it should throw an std::out_of_range exception when out-of-bounds so avoiding exception handling isn't possible here.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone on stackoverflow.com can determine the problem. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: If you don't handle the exception somewhere, then yeah, it will abort with a core dump. Not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: I've tried to use a catch but it wouldn't work, possibly the syntax was wrong or something? So because it wasn't working I removed it. How would I go about adding a catch to this function? I've tried understanding try-catch online but with this specific example I've been left really confused on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's your question coz it seems like you're already aware of the solution, i.e. catch the `std::out_of_range exception` in your caller. If the exception isn't caught by some function during stack unwinding, then `std::terminate` will be called at `main()`.

Comment: I've tried to use a catch but it wouldn't work, possibly the syntax was wrong or something? So because it wasn't working I removed it.  How would I go about adding a catch to this function?

Comment: `std::out_of_range` is derived from `std::exception`, so you could wrap your main() in a try-catch like this:
```
try
{
   //all code
}
catch (const std::exception& ex)
{
    //Handling code
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought about doing too but the exception handling has to be done in the at(index) function or this would be way easier.

Comment: In that case, you can move the same block into the `at()` code. You said that wasn't working, can you post the full code (including the push_back) so that we can see the error?

Comment: ~~~
template <typename T>
T & MyVector<T>::at(int index)
{
  try
  {
      if(index >= data_size)
         throw std::out_of_range ("Index out of range!");
      return m_data[index];
  }
  catch (const std::exception& ex)
  {
     //returning last element
     std::cout << "Exception caught\n";
     return m_data[data_size-1];
  }
}

~~~

Comment: thanks! it still returns the value 0 which I was hoping to avoid but now the exception is being thrown thankfully :)